# Order data table of users navigation paths based on previous page (like parent child relationship)

Tags: r, tidyverse

What will be the most efficient solution to order a data table based on a parent -> child relationship?

Given this nibble:

```
df <- tribble(
~user,   ~page,    ~from,
"user1", "home",  "-",
"user1", "product page",  "home",
"user1", "checkout",  "promotion",
"user1", "promotion",  "product page",
"user2", "home",  "-",
"user2", "promotion",  "home",
"user2", "checkout",  "promotion" )
```

I want to produce this output:

```
df_results <- tribble(
~user,   ~page,    ~from,   ~order,
"user1", "home",  "-",     1,
"user1", "product page",  "home", 2,
"user1", "promotion",  "product page", 3,
"user1", "checkout",  "promotion", 4,
"user2", "home",  "-",     1,
"user2", "promotion",  "home", 2,
"user2", "checkout",  "promotion",  3 )
```

It's quite simple to identify the root element using something like:

```
df_results <- df %>% 
  mutate(order = if_else( from=="-",
                          1,
                          0)) %>% 
  group_by(user)
```

But I can't figure out any solution that not involve a “for” loop to go further with the sorting.
The row in tibble for each users can be longer as the navigation step user performed on a website and pages has not a predefined order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `data.table` + `igraph`

```
library(data.table)
library(igraph)
setDT(df)[
  ,
  order := distances((g <- graph_from_data_frame(.SD[, .(ifelse(from == "-", page, from), page)])),
    v = "home",
    to = V(g)[match(.SD[, page], V(g)$name)]
  ) + 1,
  user
]
```

which gives

```
> df
    user         page         from order
1: user1         home            -     1
2: user1 product page         home     2
3: user1     checkout    promotion     4
4: user1    promotion product page     3
5: user2         home            -     1
6: user2    promotion         home     2
7: user2     checkout    promotion     3
```

Comment: Nice and clean! Just for my understanding, is the data.table needed by the igraph package or just a better overall choice for speed and memory optimization?

Comment: @Ilproff_77 I used `data.table` just because it helps speed up and is easy to group. You can use `dplyr` with `igraph` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a grouping variable and use `seq_along`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(as.integer(stringr::str_extract(user, "\\d+")), 
                 as.integer(stringr::str_extract(replace(from, from == "-", 0),"\\d+"))) %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(user) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(order = seq_along(user)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

**Output**

```
 user  page  from  order
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 user1 page1 -         1
2 user1 page2 page1     2
3 user1 page3 page2     3
4 user1 page4 page3     4
5 user2 page1 -         1
6 user2 page2 page1     2
7 user2 page3 page2     3
```

Comment: Yes, but what about a data frame that is not already ordered?

Comment: Then use `factor` to convert `from` and then you can use `arrange` to sort it based on the factor levels within each `user`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could extract the numeric values from `from` and sort that way. In the above code in the `arrange` function I've temporarily replace `"-"` with zero so the column sorts numerically. Be careful of sorting string values as you may get unwanted behavior. For example, "user10" will be sorted before "user2" if you sort directly on strings.

Comment: Sorry MC I realize that I was not enough clear, just update the question, hope this help to clarify what I’m trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat simpler solution, also using `dplyr` and `seq_along()`, but does the ordering you requested:

```
# Create sample data
df <- tribble(
  ~user,   ~page,    ~from,
  "user1", "page1",  "-",
  "user1", "page2",  "page1",
  "user1", "page4",  "page3",
  "user1", "page3",  "page2",
  "user2", "page1",  "-",
  "user2", "page2",  "page1",
  "user2", "page3",  "page2" )

# Assign order column
df2 <- df %>% 
  arrange(user, page) %>% 
  group_by(user) %>% 
  mutate(order = seq_along(user)) 

# Examine results
df2
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
# # Groups:   user [2]
#   user  page  from  order
#   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 user1 page1 -         1
# 2 user1 page2 page1     2
# 3 user1 page3 page2     3
# 4 user1 page4 page3     4
# 5 user2 page1 -         1
# 6 user2 page2 page1     2
# 7 user2 page3 page2     3
```

Comment: Yes, but this works only if the page column is something I can use to order the user’s journey. I want to develop something that do not rely on page name to order.

Comment: If you have additional criteria like not being able to sort on columns you've included in your repex then you should either not include them in your repex or mention it in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question to be more clear about what I’m trying to achieve here.

Comment: I see.  So the order is actually the link path through the site.  OK.  Got it.